# Specific Challenge Sitecore 8.2.1 migration to sitecore 9.2 end to end

Tags: setup

The migration question would be around for quite long time. I need help to understand my approach is in right direction before I invest my actual migration time.
List of queries

1. sitecore .net solution is in .net framework 4.5 . Do I need to
   convert all project library and webapp to .Net framework 4.7.1?
2. We have almost 5 sitecore support dll that is related to sitecore 8.2.1 defects that we raised with sitecore support. Does these KB support dll will impact upgradation? Should we exclude such support dll while we package .net solution to deploy?
3. Is there any easy lift and shift approach for .net solution that can be look upon?
4. Is there any checklist for xdb that I need to be excluded so that migration works fine with Xconnect?

For e.g Content Delivery Analytics

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">


<sitecore>
    <settings>
      <!-- Analytics Domain Cookie -->
      <setting name="Analytics.CookieDomain" value="__SomeValue__" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: We stick with one distinct and concrete question per post here. Also; this is not the place to come seeking upgrade advise, we have the Community Forums and [Slack](https://sitecore.chat) for this purpose.